# where to put index?

Tags: database, nosql

The system is provide POI service. Client sent HTTP request with current lat/lng, the server return all POI around it in radius like 10 miles. The data is stored in KV store. The index is going to use Geohash. Where should I put the index(geohashs) to?  The architecture is like below: 
Load balancer -> http endpoint service -> KV store. Should I put the index into http endpoints or kv store machine?

Answer (score 0):

Putting them to KV is a better idea, as you can get the availability and partition tolerance of the KV store. Putting them in the http endpoints will require you to replicate it for all the end points to ensure availability, if your geohash index is big you can't distributed easily over the endpoints.